# phpmyadmin Token Mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I get the error "Token Mismatch in phpmyadmin whenever I use the page number drop down to browse my database. Everything else seems to function fine, but I can't properly browse the database with the current error.

[image: error image]

I've tried all the various suggested solutions I could find here for the "Error: Token Mismatch" in phpMyAdmin but nothing has fixed my Token Mismatch error.
I've tried un-commenting session.save_path = /tmp
I've also clearned my cache/cookies and cleaned my temp folders.

I'm running phpmyadmin 4.7.0 with apache and mySQL

Comment: Hey Matt, is there a chance you are using a VPN/proxy service? I get this issue all the time when browsing the File Manager and phpMyAdmin due to the VPN.

Comment: May be a useful link: https://www.interserver.net/tips/kb/fix-token-mismatch-error-phpmyadmin/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone, I ended up re-installing phpmyadmin and mysql and that fixed the problem.